# Only print ARRAY[i][j] not ARRAY[j][i].... Remove diagonal elements of 2D array

Tags: c, arrays

I want to print the [i][j] elements of array, and leaving [j][i] elements.

```
void printWeightList() {
        //How many links there are: numOfEdges
        int ARRAY[MAX][MAX];
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < MAX; j++) {
                ARRAY[i][j] = weightList[i][j];
            }
        }
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < vertexCount; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < vertexCount; j++) {
                if (ARRAY[i][j] != 0) {
                    printf("%c -> %c: ", lstVertices[i] ->label, lstVertices[j] ->label);
                    printf("%d\n", ARRAY[i][j]);
                    ARRAY[j][i] = 0;    //TO REMOVE [j][i] ELEMENTS
                }
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

Above is one solution I think of this. I don't want to change weightList[][] because it's globally defined, so I create another array. This increases space complexity. I want a less complex solution.
[image: Remove Diagonal Elements. Like (A, S), (B, S)]

Comment: My code is written in 'c', but it's general program logic question that can hold for any language.

Comment: Please show desired output compared to current output and explain what is wrong. What are "[i][j]" elements as opposed to "[j][i]" elements? Do you mean elements of ARRAY[i][j] for which i<j and those for which i>j?

Comment: You might make your goal clearer if you show examples with different numbers as values. An example with 36 times 0 or 1 is not as obvious as one with numbers 0...35.

Comment: For NxM field, going through all rows and all columns and setting ARRAY[row][column] = 0 wll set all elements to 0 just as thoroughly as setting all ARRAY[column][row]=0. (For M==N). That is what makes your question so unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition that you need to check for the main diagonal is when j is equal to i.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void printWeightList(void);

#define MAX     6

int weightList[MAX][MAX] = { 1, 2, 4 , 5 , 6, 7,
                             8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,
                             14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
                             20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25,
                             26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31,
                             32, 33, 34, 34, 35, 36,
                            };

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    printWeightList();

    return(0);
}



void printWeightList(void) {

   int ARRAY[MAX][MAX];
   int i = 0;
   int j = 0;

   for ( i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < MAX; j++) {
         /*If we are on the main diagonal clear its elements*/
         if (i == j) {
            ARRAY[i][j] = 0;
         }
         else
         {
            ARRAY[i][j] = weightList[i][j];
         }
      }
   }

   for ( i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        for ( j = 0; j < MAX; j++) {
            printf("%d\t", ARRAY[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

   return;
}
```